# Accessing Google Cloud Pubsub over HTTP 2 using grpc and protobuf (generated client)

Tags: protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub, grpc

I am attempting to use the google cloud pubsub service by using the service definitions at https://github.com/google/googleapis/blob/master/google/pubsub/v1/pubsub.proto

I am able to generate the client code and have the following code to get a topic:

```
        ManagedChannelImpl channelImpl = NettyChannelBuilder
                .forAddress("pubsub.googleapis.com", 443)
                .negotiationType(NegotiationType.TLS)
                .build();

        ClientAuthInterceptor interceptor = new ClientAuthInterceptor(
                GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(SCOPES),
                ForkJoinPool.commonPool());
        Channel channel = ClientInterceptors.intercept(channelImpl, interceptor);
        PublisherBlockingClient publisher = newBlockingStub(channel);
        Topic topicInstance;
        try {
            topicInstance = publisher.getTopic(GetTopicRequest.newBuilder().setTopic(topic).build());
            if (topicInstance != null) {
                logger.info("Found existing topic: {}", topicInstance.getName());
                return publisher;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.info("Unable to find topic: {}", topic);
        }
```

This always fails with a 404. The network traffic (in DEBUG logging) seems to confirm that the client is hitting the wrong endpoint (for a publish message request):

```
DEBUG 2015-12-17 00:58:07,962 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-0] i.g.n.NettyClientTransport: 
----------------OUTBOUND--------------------
HEADERS: streamId=5, headers=DefaultHttp2Headers[:authority: pubsub.googleapis.com:443, :path: /google.pubsub.v1.Publisher/Publish, :method: POST, :scheme: https, authorization: Bearer ya29.TQIWiptEf4KsAKObPIaLaJRcq49SQ2vAutO4eIC-kgM4XwvX9p-9sFBR4eNfzE_yLiBs1A, content-type: application/grpc, te: trailers, user-agent: grpc-java-netty/0.9.0], streamDependency=0, weight=16, exclusive=false, padding=0, endStream=false
------------------------------------
DEBUG 2015-12-17 00:58:07,975 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-0] i.g.n.NettyClientTransport: 
----------------OUTBOUND--------------------
DATA: streamId=5, padding=0, endStream=true, length=725, bytes=00000002d00a136465765f616368617568616e2d6576656e747312b8050af9047b22486f7374223a226c6f63616c686f73743a3434303830222c22436f6e6e65...
------------------------------------
DEBUG 2015-12-17 00:58:11,492 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-0] i.g.n.NettyClientTransport: 
----------------INBOUND--------------------
HEADERS: streamId=5, headers=DefaultHttp2Headers[:status: 404, date: Thu, 17 Dec 2015 08:58:08 GMT, content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8, server: ESF, content-length: 1595, x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block, x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options: nosniff, alternate-protocol: 443:quic,p=1, alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=604800; v="30,29,28,27,26,25"], padding=0, endStream=false
------------------------------------
DEBUG 2015-12-17 00:58:26,357 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-0] i.g.n.NettyClientTransport: 
----------------INBOUND--------------------
DATA: streamId=5, padding=0, endStream=true, length=1595, bytes=3c21444f43545950452068746d6c3e0a3c68746d6c206c616e673d656e3e0a20203c6d65746120636861727365743d7574662d383e0a20203c6d657461206e61...
------------------------------------
DEBUG 2015-12-17 00:58:26,357 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-0] i.g.n.NettyClientTransport: 
----------------INBOUND--------------------
PING: ack=false, length=8, bytes=0000000000000002
------------------------------------
DEBUG 2015-12-17 00:58:26,358 [grpc-default-worker-ELG-0] i.g.n.NettyClientTransport: 
----------------OUTBOUND--------------------
PING: ack=true, length=8, bytes=00000000000000
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is the pubsub over HTTP 2 (using the protobuf) supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Dec 17 2015, we have not enabled gRPC on the `pubsub.googleapis.com` endpoint. Now we're actively testing gRPC support and hopefully we can make it available in the near future.

Comment: Is this still valid? I saw some grpc-samples at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-pubsub-samples-java/tree/master/grpc and was wondering if it is possible.